# No Admin rights and all info being downloaded

Tags: mac, administrator

I've been hacked by a person that knows all my info and now probably more about my Mac than I do and I don't have any Admin rights anymore. HELP! what can I do?

Comment: First thing you need to do is disconnect from the internet. The hacker does need you to have internet if he wants to hack you. Secondly you need to adjust every single password you have.

Comment: Back up whatever you can to a _new_ back-up disc; otherwise, your existing back-ups may be compromised. Then reinstall from scratch and run virus checks on each of your back-ups before trying to use any of them. (After following @LPChip's advice, of course.)

Comment: After disconnecting the infected system from the Internet, the first thing to do is to change your passwords - especially your email password, then your banking password, and then any others you care about.

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly, any sites you bought things from, paid bills, accessed banks, credit card sites, and even healthcare and retirement... put all of those accounts on hold ASAP! If you have done any of those things from this MAC, I would even put a lock/freeze on your credit (see https://krebsonsecurity.com/2015/06/how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-embrace-the-security-freeze/ ).

Go to annualcreditreport.com and get free copies of your credit report to make sure there are no NEW lines of credit.

If you find something, notify whatever agency was used for the credit. Your credit card comapanies and banks will be able to help you.